# APC (Alternative PHP Cache) optimization option

Tags: php, optimization, apc

I'm currently using the APC opcode cache, thus I disabled Zend's optimizer. Moreover, I don't have the apc.optimization flag set. Is the APC's opcode optimizer worth switching on and at what level should it be set?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment there are http://pecl.php.net/package/optimizer .

"Description: An opcode optimizer for PHP to be used with the APC opcode cache."

But this project seems frozen: Ver 0.1alpha1, alpha, 2008-08-07

I have searched a lot for infomation about apc.optimization & APC's opcode optimizers -- what is that option and how it should work. It seems that work on APC "optimization" feature is just in beginning mode.
Hope we'll get it soon!